# How do I include another login page and direct the user to one of the two login pages based on his url?

Tags: java, jsp

Here is my code to handle one url redirect but how do I implement two url redirects based on the user's url?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    import="com.example.common.config.RuntimeConfig" %>
    <html> 
    <head>
    <% 
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
  response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
 %>
    </head>
    <body>
   <%
    String loginURL = RuntimeConfig
                        .getProperty("example.callback.url").asString();
    // if (request.getSession() != null)
    // {
 //     request.getSession().invalidate();
    // }
    //Take the user back to the login page
  response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: welcome. For code blocks, select and click the `101010` button (or indent 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the current request URI (the part after the domain name) by [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29)

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
```

---

You can compare a `String` with another `String` using [`java.lang.String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods like [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), [`startsWith()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29), [`endsWith()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29), etcetera.

```
boolean equal = uri.equals("/expectedurl");
```

---

You can control the flow in Java code conditionally using [`if-else` statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

```
if (someCondition) {
    // Do something.
} else {
    // Do something else.
}
```

Do the math.

---

That said, this job [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) be done in a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) rather than a JSP file.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Does all of the code you suggested go into the filter class?